# Converter data datetime para dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, gridview

Tenho uma *GridView* e estou usando *TemplateField* para exibir a data que atualmente está no formato `string yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00´.

Preciso mostrar essa data só com `dd/MM/yyyy`.
Já tentei usar `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` e não funciona.
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Qual formato ela está? yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm?

Comment: Estou convertendo pra string em um momento então ela vem "dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00", mas preciso que exiba só dd/MM/yyyyy.

Answer (score 4):

O seguinte código formata corretamente a data, confirme se o seu código está equivalente:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "data_inicio", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Após receber mais algumas informações por comentário, fiquei sabendo que a propriedade usada na coluna do grid não é do tipo DateTime. Para que apareça com o formato desejado, será necessário converter para DateTime e depois formatar novamente como `string`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Data")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Porém sugiro que não faça a conversão da propriedade para `string` e mande o `DateTime` para o Grid.

Comment: Cara, não funcionou. Preciso chamar algo na página para ler esse DataBinder ?

Comment: Hoje está assim,

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data Início">
         <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval("data_inicio", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
         </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: O seu código esta certo também, o Eval com os argumentos que esta passando estão corretos. Tem certeza que a propriedade `data_inicio` é do tipo `DateTime`?

Comment: Não, a propriedade data inicio é string. Ai eu to convertendo pra fazer a pesquisa pelo o que o banco aceita que é yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Não vai rolar então, essa string de format "dd/MM/yyyy" somente o DateTime entende. Sugiro editar sua pergunta para incluir a informação que está trabalhando com uma string no grid e não com DateTime.